# Laravel Auto Routes Like Codeigniter - Custom Solution

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, routes

When i didn't find any best solution for auto route so i write my code.

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

---

In your **routes.php** file write this line at the end of the file

```
Route::match(["get","post"], '/{controller}/{method?}/{parameter?}', "Routes@index");
```

Now Create a new class in App\HTTP\Controllers

**Routes.php** (you can change name)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class Routes extends Controller
{

public function index($controller,$method="",$parmeter=""){
    $controller = ucfirst($controller);

    if(empty($method)){
        // e.g: example.com/users 
        // will hit App\Http\Controllers\Users\Users.php Class Index method
        return \App::call("App\Http\Controllers\\$controller\\$controller@index");          
    }



    // e.g: example.com/users/list
    // will hit App\Http\Controllers\Users\Users.php Class List method
    // If user.php has List method then $parameters will pass
    $app = \App("App\Http\Controllers\\$controller\\$controller");
    if(method_exists($app, $method)){
        return $app->$method($parmeter);
    }



    // If you have a folder User and have multiple class in users folder, and want to access other class
    // e.g: example.com/users/groups
    // will hit App\Http\Controllers\Users\Groups.php Class Index method
    $method = ucfirst($method); //Now method will be use as Class name
    $app = \App("App\Http\Controllers\\$controller\\$method");
    return $app->index();
}

}
```

> DONE

Now create your Classes in Controllers Folder and it will auto route...

Your file structure E.g:

```
App
   HTTP
     Controllers
        Users
          Users.php
          Groups.php
          Etc.php

        Post
          Post.php

        Banners
          Banners.php

        Folder
          File.php
```

Now you have idea, You can change logic according to your style, or you can use this it will work.

*I am using Laravel 5.2*

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: No question, i provide solution for auto route, But any suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: When you posted this, didn't the fact that you had to press a button labelled "Ask Question" indicate that you should only use that button to ask questions? While I do appreciate this is sharing of code, this is not the appropriate place to do that, StackExchange has places like CodeReview that would be acceptable places for these sorts of posts.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, this could be the solution for you.

Laravel has these built in methods for its controller

```
<?php

class TestsController extends BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}

}
```

Route can be defined using following syntax :

```
<?php

Route::resource('tests', 'TestsController');
```

These actions will be handled:

- GET  /tests tests.index
- GET  /tests/create tests.create
- POST /tests  tests.store
- GET  /tests/{id} tests.show
- GET  /tests/{id}/edit tests.edit
- PUT/PATCH /tests/{id} tests.update
- DELETE /tests/{id}   tests.destroy

Comment: Here i give solution about auto routing, and you didnt talk about auto routes? .... You are right about built in functions, but i only use index method, and write my logics, i call other methods from index.